# Linking Facebook to ParseUser

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I am not sure if I am missing a step in the process of linking a Facebook account to an *existing* Parse User.

**This is the code I am using, as per Parse.com**

```
if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(currentUser)) {
    ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithReadPermissionsInBackground(currentUser, getActivity(), null, new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException ex) {
            if (ex == null) {
                if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(currentUser)) {
                    Log.d("MyApp", "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am not receiving any type of error, and it will successfully open up the Facebook activity to accept/cancel giving access to my application. The issue that I am finding, is that the authData section inside my User record, inside Parse, is never populated.

**What am I doing wrong that my Parse User is not receiving any authData?**

Comment: Your code is correct, that should be adding the Facebook information to your User table. Can you reproduce this with other users and other apps?

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to add the code to fragment?
If you do that, you should consider about onActivityForResult.
As you know, onActivityForResult is not called normally.